# Why did my cron job run twice when the clocks went back?

Tags: cron

The clocks went back an hour last night at 2am - British Summer Time ended. My backup job is scheduled to run daily at 01:12. It ran twice. This is on a Debian Lenny server.

man cron says:

> if the time has moved backwards by less than 3 hours, those jobs that fall into the repeated time will not be re-run

The crontab entry is:
`12  1 * * * /home/lawnjam/bin/backup.sh`

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, turns out it's a Debian bug.
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=217836

Fixed in cron 3.0pl1-109, but Lenny is still on 3.0pl1-105.

Comment: First reported in 2003! That's a speedy fix...

Comment: That's why I never schedule any cron jobs to run between 1am and 3am. Glad to see this bug will be gone in Debian Squeeze.